# Function relation proof

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

Let function $$f(x,y)$$ such as $$f(f(x+y))=x-f(y)$$ for every $$x,y$$ that belongs to $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $$f(x) + f(-x) = 2*f(0)$$ .

Is it correct for this problem to set $$x=0$$ and then from that prove that the function is $$f(x)=-x$$ and thus prove the second relation?

Comment: This makes not sense.  $f(x,y)$ takes two variables but you immediate drop that condition immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generally conclude from $f(f(y))=-f(y)$ for all $y\in\Bbb R$ that $f(x)=-x$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, since $f(y)$ may not be injective on $\Bbb R$.

A better way to solve this problem, is to set $y=-x$ to conclude $$f(-x)=x-f(f(0))$$which leads to $$f(x)=-x+b$$with $b=f(0)$. The rest of the proof follows.

Comment: Thank you. Perfect answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> $f(f(x+y))=x-f(y)$

Well, you do have for any $x$ that $f(f(0)) = f(f(-x+x) = -x - f(x)$.

So you do have that the function is $f(x) = -x-C$ where $C = f(f(0))$

So $f(x) + f(-x) = (-x-C) + (x-C) = -2C$.

Remains to show that $C= f(f(0)) = -f(0)$.

Anyhow, $f(0) = -0-C=-C$ so that's that.

Now, admittedly we weren't *asked* to solve for $C$.

And we can quit now.

.......

However:  We do have $f(f(0)) = C$ and $f(0)=-C$ and so $C= f(f(0)) = f(-C)=-(-C)-C = C-C = 0$.

So $f(x) = -x$  is the only such function that works.

(Which is fine as $f(f(x+y)) = f(-x-y) = x+y = x - (-y) = x-(-f(x))$).